# How to interact with the value of a Slider in Sailfish Silica / QML?

Tags: c++, qml, sailfish-os

I seem to be totally lost in the declaration of forms in QML. I have a C++ object with properly set Q_PROPERTies, I have access to an object of that class in the QML, and I want to use sliders in the QML. How exactly do I make the value of the Slider update the information of the properties in the object, and vise-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's anything like regular QML, then the following approaches will work.

### Context property

Use an explicit [Binding](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) or use [Slider](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-slider.html)'s valueChanged signal:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    explicit Object(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent),
        mValue(0)
    {
    }

    qreal value() const {
        return mValue;
    }

    void setValue(qreal value) {
        if (value != mValue) {
            mValue = value;
            emit valueChanged();
        }
    }
signals:
    qreal valueChanged();
private:
    qreal mValue;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Object object;

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("object", &object);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Binding {
        target: object
        property: "value"
        value: slider.value
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
        // You can also react to the valueChanged signal of Slider:
        //onValueChanged: object.value = value
    }
}
```

### Registered QML Type

Use a simple binding:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>

class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal value READ value WRITE setValue NOTIFY valueChanged)
public:
    explicit Object(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent),
        mValue(0)
    {
    }

    qreal value() const {
        return mValue;
    }

    void setValue(qreal value) {
        if (value != mValue) {
            mValue = value;
            emit valueChanged();
        }
    }
signals:
    qreal valueChanged();
private:
    qreal mValue;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Object>("Test", 1, 0, "Object");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml:**

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2

import Test 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Object {
        id: object
        value: slider.value
        onValueChanged: print(value)
    }

    Slider {
        id: slider
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still cannot apply it to my code. The problem is, that I cannot instantiate my Object object in the QML, because i need it in several QML files, therefore, I instantiated it in main() and then attached it as a property to the root context, so I can access it globally. How do I, therefore, interact with my already instantiated object in the QML?